# Powershell:option with multiple arguments

Tags: powershell, syntax, parameter-passing

I want to do something like that:

```
param (
    [String[]]${firstArray},
    [string[]]${secondArray}
    )
Write-Host "firstArray: $firstArray"
Write-Host "args: $args"
Write-Host "secondArray: $secondArray"
```

but I want it to ne called without the ","
actually the result is:

```
.\test.ps1 -firstArray args1 args2 -secondArray args3 args4
firstArray: args1
args: args2 args4
secondArray: args3
```

but I want a way to do this:

```
.\test.ps1 -firstArray args1 args2 -secondArray args3 args4
firstArray: args1 args2
args: 
secondArray: args3 args4
```

I know that it's possble to to that with a "," like that:

```
.\test.ps1 -firstArray args1, args2 -secondArray args3, args4
firstArray: args1 args2
args: 
secondArray: args3 args4
```

but I want to know if it's possible without.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible when you don't declare any function arguments (i. e. not using the `param` block). Then the automatic variable `$args` will contain all argument tokens and you can apply your own interpreting logic.

```
Function Fun {
    [String[]] $firstArray  = @()
    [String[]] $secondArray = @()
    [ref] $arrayToAppend = $null

    # For each argument token
    foreach( $token in $args ) {
        if( $token -eq '-firstArray' ) {
            # Enter 1st array parsing mode
            $arrayToAppend = [ref] $firstArray
        }
        elseif( $token -eq '-secondArray' ) {
            # Enter 2nd array parsing mode
            $arrayToAppend = [ref] $secondArray
        }
        elseif( $null -ne $arrayToAppend ) {
            # Append to either 1st or 2nd array
            $arrayToAppend.Value += $token
        }
    }

    "firstArray : $($firstArray -join ', ')"
    "secondArray: $($secondArray -join ', ')"
}

Fun -firstArray 1 2 -secondArray 3 4
```

**Output:**

```text
firstArray : 1, 2
secondArray: 3, 4
```

**Explanation:**

In the function code I'm using a [reference variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_ref?view=powershell-7.1) `$arrayToAppend`, which will refer to either the 1st or the 2nd array. So by appending to the `Value` member of this variable, we will actually append to one of both arrays.

**Notes:**

I agree with [mklement0](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66887624/7571258) that this is conceptually problematic. If another developer sees the calling code, it could confuse them, because it differs from regular PowerShell code for passing array literals.

That being said, there might be valid uses for such code, e. g. for backwards compatibility with existing tool chains.

Comment: Thanks for updating. Not to put too fine a point on it, but I don't think the don't-do-this-part should be an _afterthought_, for the sake of future readers. The OP in essence asked: how do I something PowerShell wasn't designed to do? And you gave a good answer to _that_, but in the grand scheme of things the don't-do-this aspect is more important.

Answer (score 2):

You can decorate a parameter with `ValueFromRemainingArguments`:

```
function f {
  param(
    [Parameter(ValueFromRemainingArguments)]
    [String[]]${firstArray},
    [string[]]${secondArray}
  )

  Write-Host "firstArray: $firstArray"
  Write-Host "args: $args"
  Write-Host "secondArray: $secondArray"
}
```

```
PS ~> f -secondArray 1,2,3 a b c d
firstArray: a b c d
args:
secondArray: 1 2 3
```

Comment: thanks but I want it to be possible on each argument, I'll edit my question.

Comment: @NemuraNai I'm afraid that's not possible (making PowerShell's builtin parameter binder do that for you) - your best bet would be to manually inspect `$MyInvocation` inside the function body and re-assign arguments - not something I'd recommend :-) What's your motivation for trying to evoke this very specific behavior? What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: It's an exercise, it should be called with:
`f -firstArray arg1 arg2`
or with:
`f -secondArray arg1 arg2`
so I realise it be more pertinent to use switch because firstArray and secondArray shouldn't be called together.

Answer (score 2):

[Mathias' helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66887140/45375) shows you how to use the `ValueFromRemainingArguments` parameter-attribute property to declare a parameter that collects all arguments that:

- didn't bind to any other parameters,
- which implies that they can only be *positional*, i.e. *unnamed*, meaning: *not* preceded by the parameter *name*, such as `-firstArray`

In other words: **If you use `ValueFromRemainingArguments` to declare `$firstArray` (`-firstArray`) there are only two, mutually exclusive ways to pass *multiple* (an *array of*) arguments to it**:

- By ***naming* the target parameter**, which then **requires `,`** to separate the (sub)arguments:

  - `.\test.ps1 -firstArray args1, args2 -secondArray args3, args4`
- If you want to be able **to separate the arguments *with spaces*** you **must *not* name the target parameter**, i.e. you must pass the arguments *positionally*:

  - `.\test.ps1 args1 args2 -secondArray args3, args4`

PowerShell doesn't allow you to mix these two approaches; that is, your desired syntax:

<del>`.\test.ps1 -firstArray args1 args2 ...`</del> does *not* work.

---

Working around this, if possible at all, would be a nontrivial amount of work, but more importantly, fighting PowerShell's parameter syntax to superimpose custom logic is *conceptually* problematic, not least because it will only work with *your* scripts/functions, not generally.